# GWT Event Bus for which benefits

Tags: java, gwt

I am having a hard time to understand the benefits of using the Event Bus concept in GWT .
I have gone through many examples showing how to use it. I get how it is made but i dont see why it does help .

I take example  :

```
Button button = new Button("click");
 button.addListener(new ButtonListenerAdapter(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(Button button, EventObject e) {
        doSomething() ;// must replace it with fireEvent  later :(
    }

});
```

In order to add the  event bus ability to the code above we have to introduce more code:

1)create an event class that extends Event (implement 2 methods)

2) create interface for event handler where dosomething() will be abstract

3) Implement the interface

4) The class in which the event happens has to implement HasHandler interface, intreoduce HandlerManager instance ,implement fireEvent , registers the event and   fires the event.

Now my problem is that, if i have 50 UI events, i cant see the benefit of duplicating the above 4 steps where it should be. If I dont do  it what is really the problem i am going to face.

**Edit :**

Is the fact that Events & Events handlers if they are  separated in classes makes the EventBus pattern interesting?

```
AddContactEvent.java
AddContactEventHandler.java
RemoveContactEvent.java
RemoveContactEventHandler.java
```

Comment: Using the eventbus requires a lot of boilerplate and might seem overkill for small applications. You could (should) use the gwt eventbinder to make your life a lot easier... https://github.com/google/gwteventbinder

Comment: Thank you it simplifies some code writing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No event bus**

*Example:* You can buy apples from the farm directly.

`Button` maintains the collection of listeners. `Button` is aware about all listeners and needs to notify them in the loop. `Button` is directly coupled with the handlers.

**Event bus**

*Example:* You buy apples from a store and store buys apples from the farm. The store is a broker between you and the farm. You are not aware about the farm. The farm is not aware about you.

Event bus is broker between the event producer and event consumer. Event producer is aware about event bus but not all event consumers.

`Button` is not aware about the listeners. It's aware about EventBus only. 
Handlers are not aware about the `Button`. They are aware about the bus.

**Summary:**

Applications without plugins may be implemented without event bus.

Applications with plugin support should be implemented with the event bus as it's not known before hand how many plugins are connected to the event producer.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I will meditate on the button part of your response.

Comment: I think my problem is where to declare the event and where to declare a subsricption to that event.